# Content not updating on changing tabs in viewpager - Tablayout

Tags: android

I am  storing dynamic ids from arraylist to each tabs that are created dynamically and

I have used ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener , and it is getting id of the tab that is clicked and stores it in a sharedpreference.

I am using that id from sharedpreference  into fragment get the customlist in each tab based on that id.

NOw, the problem is the customlist is not getting refreshed on tab click , but it has already fetched old values , its not getting updated as per the id from the sharedpreference

```js
public class ScrollableTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    ArrayList<String> al,idal,pidal;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);


        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();


        al = new ArrayList<String>();
        idal = new ArrayList<String>();
        pidal = new ArrayList<String>();


        ScrollableTabsActivity.DoLogin doLogin = new ScrollableTabsActivity.DoLogin();
        doLogin.execute("");


    }

    private void setupTags() {
        int i;



        for(i=0;i<al.size();i++) {
          /*  Tag t= new Tag();
            t.setId(idal.get(i));
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setTag(t);
*/

            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setTag(idal.get(i));

        }

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager){
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabSelected(tab);

             //   CharSequence numTab = ((Tag)tab.getTag()).getId();
                CharSequence numTab = tab.getTag().toString();

                SharedPreferences preferences2 = getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME2", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = preferences2.edit();

                editor2.putString("tabselected",numTab.toString());
                editor2.putString("Authentication_Status", "true");
                editor2.apply();



            }

        });
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<al.size();i++){

        adapter.addFrag(new MainActivity(), al.get(i),idal.get(i));

        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentId = new ArrayList<>();


        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

                return mFragmentList.get(position);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();

        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title,String id) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            mFragmentId.add(id);

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_cart:
                cart();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Launching new activity
     * */
    private void cart() {
        Intent i = new Intent(ScrollableTabsActivity.this, Cart.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(500);
        MainActivity m= new MainActivity();
        m.vacatelist();

    }

    public class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

            if(isSuccess) {
                SharedPreferences preferences2 = getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME2", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = preferences2.edit();

                editor2.putString("tabselected",idal.get(0).toString());
                editor2.putString("Authentication_Status", "true");
                editor2.apply();

                setupViewPager(viewPager);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                setupTags();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(ScrollableTabsActivity.this,r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {
                    String query = "SELECT ID,Category_ItemName,Pi_Category_ID FROM [dbo].[MainMenuDetail] where Pi_Category_ID=0 and Delete_category=0";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        idal.add(rs.getString("ID"));
                        al.add(rs.getString("Category_ItemName"));
                        pidal.add(rs.getString("Pi_Category_ID"));

                    }
                    z = "Successful";
                    isSuccess=true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = "Exceptions";
            }

            return z;
        }

    }
}
```

```js
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
 // Log tag

 private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
 ConnectionClass connectionClass;
 // Movies json url
 String url="http://i.imgur.com/mQPXunb.png";
 private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
 private ListView listView;
 private CustomListAdapter adapter;
 private List templist = new ArrayList();
 String image_url = "http://app.dartenogroup.com/admin/img/";
 String image_url2="";
 NetworkImageView img;
 String restid;
 Movie movie;
 String tabselected;


 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
 }
 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState);

  SharedPreferences prfs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  restid = prfs.getString("restid", "");

  SharedPreferences prfs2 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  tabselected = prfs2.getString("tabselected", "");
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tabselected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
  listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
  adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);

  img = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

  // changing action bar color
  //getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
  // new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));

  DoLogin  doLogin = new DoLogin();
  doLogin.execute("");


  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Intent i2 = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewProduct.class);
    TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemid);
    i2.putExtra("value",tv.getText().toString());
    startActivity(i2);
   }
  });

 }


 /**
  * On selecting action bar icons
  * */
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Take appropriate action for each action item click
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.action_cart:
    cart();
    return true;

   default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
 }

 /**
  * Launching new activity
  * */
 private void cart() {
  Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Cart.class);
  startActivity(i);
 }

 public class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
 {
  String z = "";
  Boolean isSuccess = false;


  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   movieList.clear();
   templist.clear();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String r) {


   if(isSuccess) {

    updatelist();
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(500);
   }
   else{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),z,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  }


  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
     Connection con = connectionClass.CONN ();
     if (con == null) {
      z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
     } else {

      String query = "select * from [dbo].[MainMenuDetail] WHERE Delete_category = 0 AND Pi_Category_ID ='"+tabselected+"'" ;
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

      while (rs.next()) {

       movie = new Movie();
       movie.setId(rs.getString("ID"));
       movie.setItemname(rs.getString("Category_ItemName"));
       movie.setDescription(rs.getString("Category_SHortDesc"));
       movie.setPrice(rs.getString("Category_Price"));
       image_url2=rs.getString("show_Image");
       String img= image_url+image_url2;
       movie.setThumbnailUrl(img);
       update();
      }
      z = "Successful";
      isSuccess=true;
     }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     isSuccess = false;
     z = "Exceptions";
    }

   return z;
  }
 }

 public void updatelist(){
  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    movieList.addAll(templist);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
  });
 }
 public void refreshlist(){

  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
  }); }

 public void vacatelist(){
  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    movieList.clear();
   }
  });
 }

 public void update(){
  templist.add(movie);
 }

}
```

Comment: show some code...

Comment: Edited. Placed scrolling tab activity and the fragment that is used in all tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    CharSequence numTab = tab.getTag().toString();
    SharedPreferences preferences2 = getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME2", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = preferences2.edit();

    editor2.putString("tabselected",numTab.toString());
    editor2.putString("Authentication_Status", "true");
    editor2.apply();

    // super called last
    super.onTabSelected(tab);
}
```

or store `ViewPagerAdapter adapter` "globally" on top of `ScrollableTabsActivity` (not only inside `setupViewPager` method)

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    //rest of your code
}
```

and then

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    // your current code
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //ViewPagerAdapter's adapter
}
```

Comment: the problem is fully solved after doing the  
super.onTabSelected(tab); 
and
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 as you said. but it created a new gui problem:

 after swiping to new tab , the selected tab is not getting bold , but still on tab selection gui is working fine

Answer (score 0):

There might be several Solution to this issue i.e.

1.) Load all your data at once if you have less data and less tabs and also you can increase

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(noOfTabs);
```

2.) Update your fragment once it is visible to the user.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser){
        // load data
    }
}
```

Hope that will be helpful.